# I have an M9×75 male thread. What is the correct size nut?

Tags: threading

I'm trying to match a nut to an M9×75 male thread. What size nut am I looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Presumably you mean M9-0.75 (0.75mm thread to thread spacing, or "pitch") as that is one of the pitches for the rather oddball/rare  M9 threading [(M9-0.5, M9-1 and M9-1.25 are the others.)](https://www.engineersedge.com/hardware/metric-internal-thread-sizes1.htm)

If you actually mean you have a 75mm long M9 bolt, (So M9-0.5x75, M9-0.75x75, M9-1x75 or M9-1.25x75)  you'd need to measure the pitch, and it should be one of the above, unless it's not really a standard (to the extent that they are - they are hard to find in the average hardware store) M9 bolt at all.

In any case, you need an M9 nut of the matching pitch, if what you have is an M9 bolt.

If you mean "what size wrench would fit the nut flats" apparently a 12mm, from at least one maker - They don't show up in many standard charts at all. And the size may vary, as some 8mm nuts are 13mm flats - it depends how thick the nut is, and that can vary with application. Apart from bicycles, evidently M9-0.75 is a common threading for electronic/audio equipment potentiometers and jacks. Not one seller's specs have mentioned the wrench flat size for those, though they can be seen to be quite thin.

Comment: The nuts on M9 potentiometers and sockets are considerably smaller than on M9 bike axles. I reckon you could need anything from a 12mm spanner to 17mm depending on the application, with 13mm or 15mm being most likely for simple nuts.